# Can you use a DataContext directly with MySql without mapping to entities in a diagram?

Tags: mysql, .net, database, datacontext

Can you use a DataContext directly with MySql without mapping to entities in a diagram?

Meaning I want to instantiate a datacontext using the connectionstring to mysql, but without first reading out the database and mapping it in a diagram. (I'd rather do this in code)

Comment: I think I already found a partial solution, byt mapping my class model using the `[Table]` attribute?

    `using System.Data.Linq.Mapping;

    [Table]
    public class CountryModel : BaseTableModel`

Comment: I've been testing around with `DataContext` and MySql but no luck so far, does anybody have an idea?